# ABCD is a parallelogram, and AXY is a straight line through A meeting BC at X and DC at Y. Prove that BX.DY is constant.

Tags: geometry, triangles, congruences-geometry

I'm not able to figure out what "constant" here means. I proved it till AB.AD = BX.DY but how is this value constant I don't get it. If we put different values of sides AB and AD we would get different answers. It would be a great help if someone corrects me. Thanks.

Here's the proof :

In ΔABX and ΔYDA

∠XAB = ∠AYD

∠XBA = ∠ADY

Therefore, ΔABX ~ ΔYDA

⇒ AB/DY=BX/AD

Hence, AB.AD = BX.DY

Comment: Constant means for a  given parallelogram. So if you got AB*AD = BX*DY  you have it proved

Comment: Include some work you did, perhaps your proof of AB.AD=BX.DY. [if you do not show an effort question likely gets closed]

Comment: He had a specifique question and a prove. So why should it be closed.

Comment: @coffeemath I have updated my post. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll be mindful next time.

Comment: @trula Remember that questions can be edited. There question didn't have a proof when first posted.

Comment: @roli Did my comment answer your question, I think it should

Comment: @trula Yes, it did. Thank you very much :)